# App packing error due to drawable resource

Tags: android, android-resources, screen-resolution

My error is:

```
\res\drawable-hdpi\blue.PNG: error: File is case-insensitive equivalent to: \res\drawable-ldpi\blue.png
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Change this \res\drawable-hdpi\blue.`PNG` to this \res\drawable-hdpi\blue.`png` . Just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `\res\drawable-hdpi\blue.PNG` to `\res\drawable-hdpi\blue.png`. That's exactly what it says in your error.

Comment: Yes, we just need to change and the app runs :)

Answer (score 1):

you cant have any uppercase letters in your drawable filenames (Including the extension of the file). Just change it from `blue.PNG` to `blue.png`

Answer (score 0):

remember that resources for android can not contain numbers or letters all capital letters or symbols

yo can edit blue.PNG to blue.png and your project worked